# Error while saving the data in database

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm using this code to save the values to access database

What i have done .

- Added the database to project
- Binded the databindings to textboxes
- On form load i got the values from database to textboxes ( So i did it correctly )
- On button one i add the new field with this code

Code :

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button2.Click
               TabelaBindingSource.AddNew()
           End Sub
```

And on button save i add this code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        Validate()
        TabelaBindingSource.EndEdit()
         TabelaTableAdapter.Update(EUUsersDataSet.tabela)
        MessageBox.Show("Saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error during saving")
    End Try
End Sub
```

It pop ups me box "Saved" but there is no record in database  What i did wrong ?

I tried to add it through the TabelaBindingNavigator even when i hit save on that button still wont save it.

Comment: You should have an INSERT INTO statement, give it some values, and add it some parameters.

Comment: Like doing with mysql databases ? I thought because its binded i could avoid that ?

Comment: I tried that before... It didn't work. If you are happy then I would give you the source in my answer.

Comment: @CodingSource If you can i would try also that.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TabelaTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Table1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.TabelaBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TabelaBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TabelaAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error during saving")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: why you think i downvote your answer ? 
http://pokit.org/get/?65c371a0e5470c149c5de4ee1c74f2d9.jpg

Comment: Maybe this does the trick: Go to Data Sources -> Right mouse click on datset -> Configure with wizard -> Go through the wizard -> rename new to your old table name.